# I can not choice in eclipse Qvga 240x320

Tags: eclipse, layout

I can not choice in eclipse Qvga 240x320 2.7 for small layout.Graphical layout no work...I have message 
Exception raised during rendering: Index: 1, Size: 1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
Why?How i fix it?Avd manager has virtual device qvga.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do Yu have an AddView inside?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
It's a [bug in the rendering library](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37472) soved in SDK 16.2 or avobe.
You must install a SDK 16.2 or later and select it in the layout editor.